# When health reaches 0, the paragraph doesn't change

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I don't know why the 'test' paragraph doesn't change when it reaches 0. What do I do wrong? I tried to put 'damage', 'heal' inside the 'if-statement', but it didn't work. The condition is pretty simple so I have no idea what went wrong.

And also, how can I stop the functions when the health is less than 0 or more than 100?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>SMTH</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <p id="health">Enemy's health: </p>
        <dl>
            <dd id="plus">+100</dd>
            <dd id="minus">-100</dd>
        </dl>
        <p id="test"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="script/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

let healthS = document.getElementById('health');
let plus = document.getElementById('plus');
let minus = document.getElementById('minus');

health = 100;

let damage = ()=>{
    health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
    healthS.innerHTML = "Enemy's health: " + health;
}

let heal = ()=>{
    health += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    healthS.innerHTML = "Enemy's health: " + health;
}

minus.onclick = damage;
plus.onclick = heal;


if(health > 80){
    test.innerHTML = "Alive";
}else if(health <= 0){
    test.innerHTML = "Dead";
}
```

Comment: Maybe im missing it but `test` doesnt seem to be defined anywhere? `let test = document.getElementById('test');`

Comment: hmm, now when you said it. The code actually works without declaration. Don't know how.

Comment: Some browsers create global vars from id. Safer to use `getElementById` rather than depend on this behavior though.

Comment: Oh, that is how it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the if statements inside the heal and damage functions. Outside the functions they are called once on document load only. so the status never changes

```js
let healthS = document.getElementById('health');
let plus = document.getElementById('plus');
let minus = document.getElementById('minus');

var health = 100;

let damage = () => {

  health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
  if(health<=0)
  {
  health=0;

  }
  healthS.innerHTML = "Enemy's health: " + health;
  
  if (health > 80) {
    test.innerHTML = "Alive";
  } else {
    test.innerHTML = "Dead";
  }
  
}

let heal = () => {
  health += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  healthS.innerHTML = "Enemy's health: " + health;
  if (health > 80) {
    test.innerHTML = "Alive";
  } else {
    test.innerHTML = "Dead";
  }
}

minus.onclick = damage;
plus.onclick = heal;
if (health > 80) {
  test.innerHTML = "Alive";
} else {
  test.innerHTML = "Dead";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>SMTH</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <p id="health">Enemy's health: </p>
    <dl>
      <dd id="plus">+100</dd>
      <dd id="minus">-100</dd>
    </dl>
    <p id="test"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="script/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I tried to Upvote your answer, but it says I can't do it right now)

Comment: mark it as correct. Check the tick beside the answer. You dont have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: May I ask you one more thing? How can I quit the function when health reaches 0?

Comment: I have edited the answer check it. Just make the health zero as soon as it goes below 0